# ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, screen, cuda-driver

When I run my code with TensorFlow directly, everything is normal.

However, when I run it in a screen window, I get the following error.

```
ImportError: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have tried the command:

```
source /etc/profile
```

But it doesn't work.

Cause I use ssh to connect to the servers, the screen is necessary.

How can I fix it?

Comment: If you do not have Cuda installed, install it at: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html

Comment: This can happen also after simply trying to `import cupy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put `libcuda.so.1` path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable.

example:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/of/libcuda.so.1:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: THX！But it doesn't work. I run your command and then update the profile with : ` source /etc/profile ` and ` source bash_profile `, they either don't work. Are there any other methods?

Comment: THX! It worked. But the ` $LD_LIBRARY_PATH ` should be found manually.

Comment: You can put the above code in ~/.bashrc so everytime you open up a terminal the code will execute and update the LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Answer (score 14):

Steps to follow:
Find **libcuda.so.1**:

```
echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH #path
sudo find /usr/ -name 'libcuda.so.*' #version
```

Then add to **$LD_LIBRARY_PATH**, in my case `/usr/local/cuda-10.0/compat`, with the following command, in terminal:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.0/compat
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Background

`libcuda.so.1` is the library for interacting with the CUDA driver (as opposed to CUDA's "Runtime API", for which you need `libcudart.so.*`).

Now, it's quite possible to have the CUDA *Toolkit* properly installed, without the *driver* being properly installed. And this error could be the result of building a (non-statically-linked) CUDA application in this situation.

Alternatively, it could be the case that there's some misconfiguration of the library search path - because normally, `libcuda.so.*` are supposed to be installed in some directory on that path!

So, what's on that search path? As explained [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/367600/what-is-the-order-that-linuxs-dynamic-linker-searches-paths-in), it is:

1. directories from `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
2. directories from `/etc/ld.so.conf`
3. `/lib`
4. `/usr/lib`

A typical scenario would be for `/etc/ld.so.conf` to add, say, `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`; and for `libcuda.so.*` to be there.

#### Bottom line

Here's what you should do:

1. Make sure a(n up-to-date) CUDA driver has been properly installed. If it hasn't, download and install it, problem solved.
2. Locate the `libcuda.so.1` file (e.g. using `locate`). If it's been placed somewhere weird that's not in the library search path - act as in step 1.
3. If you *wanted* the driver library installed someplace weird, *then* add that path to your user's `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Appreciate the background!

Comment: One common scenario where this may happen is not passing the `--gpus` argument to various `docker` commands, as explained [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#gpu). That will result in the driver library not being present in your container.

Answer (score 0):

As my condition, I develop in docker container environment, I do the following steps:

1. Confirm your docker container have run with nvidia gpu
2. Find libcuda.so.1:
   `sudo find /usr/ -name 'libcuda.so.*'`
3. Then add to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, in my case `/usr/local/cuda-11.5/compat`, with the following command, in terminal:
   `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-11.5/compat`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to run the job inside a container, try starting it with `nvidia-docker run` instead of `docker run`. Additional instructions can be found here: https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker

Answer (score 0):

First, put this in my notebook (Collab):

```
import os
os.environ['LD_LIBRARY_PATH'] += ':/usr/local/cuda-12.2/compat'

/usr/local/cuda-12.2/compat <--- This is my path (libcuda.so.1)
```

then:

```
!pip install llama.cpp
```

from git, and next copy the path in the new directory:

```
!export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:./llama.cpp/quantize
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error in google colab.
I resolved the error by setting up the runtime to T4 GPU.
T4 GPU is required so that you do not get error related to CUDA.